# C - Como posso ler dados de um ficheiro (Tendo em conta que uso estruturas para o mesmo)

Tags: c, arquivo, lista-encadeada

Boa noite.

Estou a elaborar um projeto para a Faculdade, em C, onde tenho uma estrutura de dados para trabalhar com os dados comuns aos "Infractores", ou àqueles que cometeram uma infração.

```
typedef struct Infractores
{
    int ordemdeEntrada;//ordem de entrada da infração ... começa em 1 acaba em N
    char *marca;
    char *modelo;
    char *matricula;
    double valorportagem;
    int classeVeiculo;
    struct Infractores *seguinte;
};
```

Se bem já repararam eu estou a usar apontadores para `*marca , *modelo` ... e tenho uma `struct Infractores *seguinte;`. Isto acontece por causa de ter de implementar listas no projecto.

Acontece que pretendo implementar um método para ler de um ficheiro os mais recentes infractores, por exemplo aqueles que cometeram infracções ontem. Para conseguir isto desenvolvi também um método:

```
void ListaInfractoresAnteriores(Infractores *f)
    {
        const char *filenameinfractors = "C:/Users/Vitor/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/AED II/Resolucao_Teste/Projecto/VVManager/lastdayinfractors.txt";
        FILE *ficheiroInf = fopen(filenameinfractors, "r");
        //struct TesteInfractores auxiliar;
        struct Infractores *auxiliar;
        auxiliar = f;
        while (!feof(ficheiroInf))
        {

            if (fscanf(ficheiroInf, "%d %s %s %lf %d \n", &auxiliar->ordemdeEntrada, *auxiliar->marca, *auxiliar->modelo, &auxiliar->valorportagem, &auxiliar->classeVeiculo) != NULL)
            {
                printf("Marca %s",*auxiliar->marca);
            }


        }
    }
```

Neste método tento testar em que se a entrada do meu `fscanf()` for `<>` (diferente) de `NULL` (Nulo), então ele deve escrever a marca, neste caso do carro, que cometeu a infracção.

Não consigo de maneira nenhuma ler o ficheiro usando esta estrutura de dados. Como posso ler dados do ficheiro tendo em conta **que não queria usar uma nova estrutura de dados**? Será que tenho que criar **novas variáveis**?

Nota: **Pretendo usar a estrutura de dados para manipular ficheiros e manipular listas**.

Comment: Para o que você quer fazer precisa de uma estrutura de dados para ler cada linha e armazenar cada linha lida em uma estrutura diferente. Ou cria um array de estruturas. Segundo fscanf não retorna nulo, não é necessário tal if.

Comment: Oi Vitor - eu sei que não é a sua pergunta - mas como é um caso real de manipulação de dados (e não um porblema de escola, como a maioria das questões em C)  - eu sugiro que você aborde seu problema em uma linguagemd e mais alto nível do que C. Esse é um sistema típico em que seus dados poderiam ficar num banco SQL (ou NoSQL)-e se você usar Python, Java, Ruby ou Javascript - vai ter bem menos boilerplate para usar o SQL, e a vida será bem mais tranquila

Comment: Se desejar ir pelo caminho de tentar usar outra linguagem ai - me escreva que eu posso dar uam orientação mais extensa (daí vamos documentando aqui no S.O. para os próximos se for o caso). Meu e-mail está no perfil.

Comment: Perdão  - agora que vi que também é um trabalho para a faculdade.  Então, provavlemnte você não tem opção de mudar de linguagem - e vai ter que aprender bastante pra fazer em C - preste atenção no comentário do @Anthonyacioly na resposta do Rafael abaixo.

Comment: Eu até poderia usar uma linguagem mais avançada, como java ou C#, mas o trabalho é para Algoritmos e é recomendavel, por cá usar linguagens estruturadas, em vez de linguagens orientadas a objectos

Comment: Acho bom estudar mais os conceitos básicos da linguagem (desferenciar ponteiros para estruturas, retorno de função da biblioteca padrão, uso do typedef etc), tem muitos erros bobos nesse código, erros que quem está tentando implementar algo mais complexo como uma estrutura de dados não deveria cometer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você diz que deve implementar listas encadeadas, não tem como evitar o uso dos ponteiros. Abaixo fiz uma implementação que usa a lista.
Ainda é passível de alterar a `void ListaInfractoresAnteriores(Infractores * listaDeInfratores)` de forma que você tenha a lista de Infratores na função main.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct infractores
{
    int ordemdeEntrada; //ordem de entrada da infração ... começa em 1 acaba em N
    char * marca;
    char * modelo;
    char * matricula;
    double valorportagem;
    int classeVeiculo;
    struct infractores * seguinte;

} Infractores;

Infractores * criaInfrator(int ordemDeEntrada, char * marca, char * modelo,
                           double valorportagem, int classeVeiculo){
    Infractores * f = (Infractores *) malloc (sizeof(Infractores));
    f->ordemdeEntrada = ordemDeEntrada;

    f->marca = malloc((strlen(marca)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(f->marca, marca);
    f->marca[strlen(marca)] = '\0';

    f->modelo = malloc((strlen(modelo)+1)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(f->modelo, modelo);
    f->modelo[strlen(modelo)] = '\0';

    f->valorportagem = valorportagem;
    f->classeVeiculo = classeVeiculo;
    f->seguinte = NULL;

    return f;
}

void ListaInfractoresAnteriores(Infractores * listaDeInfratores){

    int i;
    int count = 0;

    FILE *fp;

    Infractores * p;

    int ordemEntrada, classeVeiculo;
    double valorPortagem;
    char marca[10], modelo[10];

    if((fp = fopen("lastdayinfractors.txt", "r")) != NULL){

        for(i = 0; !feof(fp); i++, count++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %lf %d\n",
                   &ordemEntrada, marca, modelo,
                   &valorPortagem, &classeVeiculo);

            if(i==0){
                p = criaInfrator( ordemEntrada, marca, modelo, valorPortagem, classeVeiculo);
                listaDeInfratores = p;
            }else{
                p->seguinte = criaInfrator( ordemEntrada, marca, modelo, valorPortagem, classeVeiculo);
                p = p->seguinte;
            }
        }

        p = listaDeInfratores;
        while(p!=NULL){
            printf("Marca: %s\n", p->marca);
            p=p->seguinte;
        }

        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
        puts("Não foi possível abrir o arquivo.");
}

int main(void)
{
    Infractores * listaDeInfratores;

    ListaInfractoresAnteriores(listaDeInfratores);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: É necessário forçar ou fazer um cast quando se chega a esta instrução : f->marca = malloc((strlen(marca)+1)*sizeof(char));

Comment: Do genero f->marca = (char*)malloc((strlen(marca)+1)*sizeof(char));

Comment: Mas obrigado! @Sasha Nicolas

Comment: @VitorFerreira http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: Por que fazes então o cast de `Infractores * f = (Infractores *) malloc (sizeof(Infractores));`?

Comment: Nao sei entao o que se passa com o meu IDE ... o visual studio dá-me erro se nao fizer essa pequena modificacao

Answer (score 1):

O modo mais fácil é criar uma array de estruturas, o mais difícil seria organizar uma estrutura de dados própria. Com array, simplesmente para ler e mostrar eu faria:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

typedef struct infractores
{
   int ordemdeEntrada;
   char marca[20];
   char modelo[20];
   char matricula[20];
   double valorportagem;
   int classeVeiculo;
   struct infractores *seguinte;

} Infractores;

void ListaInfractoresAnteriores(Infractores f[]){

   int i;            /* índice dos arrays de struct */
   int n_linhas = 0; /* número linhas que serão lidas 
                        para uso no controle de exibição */

   FILE *fp;

   if((fp = fopen("problema.dat", "r")) != NULL){
      /* Percorre o arquivo até o fim incrementando o contador 
         do array struct e também o número de linhas */
       for(i = 0; !feof(fp); i++, n_linhas++)
       {
           fscanf(fp, "%d %s %s %lf %d\n", 
               &f[i].ordemdeEntrada, f[i].marca, f[i].modelo,
               &f[i].valorportagem, &f[i].classeVeiculo);   
       }
       /* Mostra até a última linha lida, que deve ter valor menor
          que a capacidade do array inserido. */
       for(i = 0; i < n_linhas; i++)
           printf("Marca: %s\n", f[i].marca);   

       fclose(fp);  
   }
   else
       puts("Não foi possível abrir o arquivo.");
}

/* Testando a função com um array de 50 structs */
int main(void)
{
   Infractores f[50];

   ListaInfractoresAnteriores(f);

   return 0;
}
```

Na qual utilizei um arquivo de 2 linhas para teste (lembrando que a matriz utilizada cabem 50 estruturas):

```
10 Ferrari Bluhm 1.999 29
20 Fusca rafael 4.54 21
```

**Saída**

```
Marca: Ferrari
Marca: Fusca
```

Agora, para usos dinâmicos das estruturas "carregadas" pelo arquivo recomendo utilizar uma estrutura de dados própria - inclusive utilizando esse ponteiro que autorreferencia a estrutura - ao invés de utilizar arrays.

Comment: Para complementar, veja que aqui o Rafael está utilizando vetores de 20  caracteres (`char marca[20]`, etc) para armazenar as strings. Caso você queira strings de tamanho dinâmico será necessário utilizar `malloc` / `realloc` (veja [exemplo no SOEn](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8164021/664577)). Analogamente o Rafael também está utilizando um array para armazenar até 50 infratores (`Infractores f[50]`), no seu caso você deve utilizar `malloc` a cada infrator / linha e atualizar o ponteiro `seguinte`.

Comment: E por um NULL no final :)

Comment: Oi Rafael  - tem uma questão  com a sua abordagem que você deveria explicar no texto da resposta: você modificou a estrutura do OP para que os dados da estrutura ficassem "inline" - de `char * marca` para `char marca[20]` - isso é necessário sim, para isso funcionar corretamente, já que os 20 chars de marca ficam de fato "dentro" da estrutura - mas também limita o tamanho dos campos, e desperdiça espaço no arquivo quando os campos não forem preenchidos

Comment: Reitero que é o jeito mais simples de fazerisso, e a resposta está boa - mas seria legsal explicar essas coisas.